# Thermodynamic derivations of quantities using fugacity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

The objective of this problem was to find a $K$ such that as $T$ changes with $V$ for an adiabatic, reversible (isentropic) process for a real gas, we get the equation
$$T_2 \approx T_1 \exp(K\Delta V)$$
So this is procedure I followed,

$$dT = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S dV + \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_V dS \\ 
dT = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S dV$$
Since process is isentropic.
Now, to simplify this in quantities we can measure, I used the triple product rule
$$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S= -\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_V\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T$$
Using Maxwell's relationships and so on, we know
$$ \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_V = -\frac{T}{C_V} \\
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T = \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V=\alpha \kappa_T$$
Using this, I say that
$$dT = -\frac{T}{C_V}\alpha \kappa _T dV\\
\frac{dT}{T}=KdV \\
\implies T_2 = T_1 K\exp (\Delta V)$$
assuming $K$ is only weakly dependent on $V$.
So $K = -\frac{\alpha \kappa _T}{C_V}$.
Let's define fugacity of this gas as $f=Pe^{bT}$.

My question is, knowing fugacity, how do you find quantities such as $K$? Can you replace pressure with fugacity in all ideal gas equation relationships we have?
$K$ is supposed to have the following form:
$$K = \frac{P}{C_P ^{IG} T - k_B T (2bT +1)}$$

How do I go about this problem?

Comment: What are T and P supposed to be in the final equation, averages over the interval?  Have you been able to figure out how the $C_P^{IG}$ comes into the analysis?